Nuc norm and L2 norm for sdp problem
I have a question about using nuclear norm for rank minimisation.
I have a SDP problem.

f(X) is convex in nature and g(x) is linear.
Now, I must apply rank minimisation and establish a relationship between X and x. So, can I apply
Norm_nuc(X) - norm(x)^2_l2<= 0
I employ first-order Taylor series approximation for norm(x)^2_l2 to make it linear.
The problem is convex and solved using cvx. But I must ask experts if this is a relèvent and correct constraint.

If x is a declared variable, which it should be, I don't see how that constraint would be accepted by CVXPY, or any other DCP tool, unless you invoked DCCP. Where does L2 norm come from?  Perhaps you want to minimize (some multiple of) norm_nuc, or maximize its negative,, as at least a term in the objective function? Do you also include the SDP constraint? You haven't told us what f(X,x) is. As it stands, it's not clear what your original optimization problem is, or what your proposed formulation is. I presume rank minimization is to try to induce $X=xx^T$ to be satisfied by solution.

@MarkL.Stone please have a look at the problem now.

Perhaps you can tell us explicitly what f(X) and g(x) are?  Are those Norm_nuc(X) and norm(x)^2_l2, and if so, are they part of your original problem, or introduced somehow as part of your rank minimization to try to induce rank one solution of what appears to be SDP relaxation of $X = xx^T$?

The rank minimization constraint does not induce them but is part of the original problem. To be exact, its X(n,n)<= (a-b)/a +  real(x(n)) and n =1,..., N, a, b are real numbers and Norm_nuc - (x)^2_l2 is introduced as an additional constraint which is to have this relaxation control X>=xx^T and also at the same time helping me to get a rank-1 solution. So, I am getting x as a rank-1 solution, which perfectly aligns with the solution I need.

If that limesarized (norm^2) upper bound on norm_nuc(X) results in a rank one solution, then you have succeeded. The only danger would be that you might be overconstraining X, and therefore not getting as good a solution (as low an objective function) as you (perhaps) could have To further investigate that, you could relax that norm_nuc constraint by adding something to the RHS, and see whether you still get a rank one solution, and if so, whether it is better (smaller objective value) than the solution you are now getting.  Alsocan    eliminate norm_nuc constraint and see whether still rank 1
